# USB inrush current limiting, charging super capacitor

Tags: current, usb, current-limiting, computers, supercapacitor

I am trying to charge a supercap over USB.  I understand I need to limit the current (ref: [usb.org](https://compliance.usb.org/index.asp?UpdateFile=Electrical#45))

This has been discussed a lot here, for example: [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/272645/limiting-supercapacitor-charging-inrush) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36375/understanding-usb-inrush-current-requirements), but I believe my requirements are a bit different and I honestly do not know why my circuit would not be sufficient.

I don't need to charge my supercap so fast, so what I have done is to place a 150 ohm resistor and then I use a small LDO that would take the voltage down to 2.8 volt which my supercap needs. If I understand ohms law, that 150 ohm resistor and 5 volt would give inruch current absolute maximum of 33.33 mA.
(5 V / 150 R = 0.03333333 A)

[image: My schematic]

I would expect this to work, but when I connected it to my computer it restarts. I don't know for sure but I assume it is because of the current limit.

If I connect it to a wall plug it works great charging the capacitor.

Any ideas?

Comment: How many milliamps is the circuit drawing now?  "My comp restarts" is not a voltmeter/ammeter, and USB voltmeter/ammeters are readily available from the cornucopia of cheap Cheese.

Comment: Your schematic is upside down. Even if you connected a charged supercap in reverse this circuit shouldn't draw more than 50mA. Something else must be making your computer restart (wiring error, wrong value resistor, ESD?)

Comment: @BruceAbbott OT but interesting that it is upside down. This i want to read more about. Do you have a reference? Wouldnt a typical computer (iMac from 2023) have decent enough ESD protection on its ports?

Comment: "3. Basic layout and flow In general, it is good to put **higher voltages towards the top, lower voltages towards the bottom** and logical flow left to right." - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics

Answer (score 2):

Use a current source after your LDO.  One ancient one is a [LM134](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm334.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1681894267257&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.co.uk%252F) but there are many to choose from.  You can set the voltage on the LDO to match the current source requirements, and set the current to whatever your USB handles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why that would cause the processor to restart.  Maybe it's not wired right (the circuit is drawn upside-down compared with the usual conventions), or your power supply hasn't got 33mA spare capacity.

Be aware that With the 150 ohm resistor placed *before* the regulator, the voltage input to the regulator will collapse the moment you connect a large load, so it won't actually regulate until the current drops down again.  But this may not be a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks. Think it should be ok as you say. Also if i put the resistor after the regulator i am affraid putting the resistor after the regulator could make it very slow or even prevent the voltage from reaching 2.8 volt?

Comment: @www.jensolsson.se It should reach 2.8V eventually, but it may take some time.  But you could probably decrease the resistor if it's after the regulator.